# 2 Column Layout Not Working

Tags: css, layout

I tried using this guy's tutorial of making a 2 column layout:
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/2-column-layout-code/

Here's how mine came out : / http://jsfiddle.net/WrpA8/

The CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#header {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your padding and border actually are eating up your content of `600px`. So, try to make it to `580px` for example and it will work.

```
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 580px;
    padding:4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

or of course you could remove padding and border altogether if you want and stay with `600px size`.

Check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WrpA8/1/)

Comment: Glad to be of help @lawm. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 3):

Border and padding contribute to an element's overall width. Try setting the border and padding to 0 and you'll see that the layout works as expected. If you want a border and padding, you'll have to factor their size in when you size the main element.